# PHP Access a method in global

Tags: php, function, oop, variables, methods

I'm triyng to convert a normal script in PHP to OO. I'me having some troubles doing that for some things. one of that is call a function (or method) in a variable to use globally.

The initial code is the following:

```
$myVariable = myFunction();

function myFunction(){
    // some code in here
}
```

I've triyed to do something like following but it doesen't work

```
class MyClass{
    $myVariable = $this->myFunction();
    
    function myFunction(){
        // some code in here
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Put in `__construct()` maybe?

Comment: ok, like this work... but how to call in other function? ```global``` for what i know is not so good

Comment: You need to give an example of where you would define it and where you would like to call it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function in a method (most likely the constructor). if you want to access to the property all over the class definition do this:

```php
// Imagine you have a global method like this
MyFunction() {
}

class MyClass {

  // define a property that store the result of calling MyFunction()
  protected $somethingThatYouNeed;

  // constructor calls when you instantiate your class
  public function __construct() {
    $this->somethingThatYouNeed = myFunction();
  }


  public function otherMethod() {
    // you can access your variable here by calling $this->somethingThatYouNeed
  }


}
```